# Dropdown-list in WPF from PowerShell

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, powershell, user-interface, combobox

I have 3 ComoboBox Items in a ComboBox:

```
<ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="340,60,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="64" Height="27">
                        <ComboBoxItem x:Name="var_Combo1" Content="DOMAIN1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="63"/>
                        <ComboBoxItem x:Name="var_Combo2" Content="DOMAIN2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="63"/>
                        <ComboBoxItem x:Name="var_Combo3" Content="DOMAIN3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="63"/>
                    </ComboBox>
```

As an example I want to run the PowerShell script below when var_Combo1 is selected:

```
(Get-ADuser -identity $var_userName.Text  -server DOMAIN 1 -Properties MemberOf).MemberOf -Replace 'CN=', '' -Replace ',.*', ''
```

and get the result in a Textblock or DataGrid and if no ComboBox is selected the Textblock or DataGrid should be empty

How can I do this as I've searched the internet and couldn't find any suitable solution.

I’d realy appreciate it if someone can assist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handle the `SelectionChanged` event and do your thing in this event handler:

```
$comboBox = $window.FindName("comboBox")
$comboBox.Add_SelectionChanged({

     Get-ADuser ...

}
```

**XAML:**

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" ... />
```